# Slider slides out on click but I don't want this

Tags: javascript, css, less, media-queries

I need css changes only to be applied in case of big screens
below does not compiles

```
&:hover:not(@media @smartphones),
&.hover-this:not(@media @smartphones) {
    width: 15rem;

    .row .label-area {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: @icon-width;
    }

    + .menu { left: 16rem; }
}
```

I have a Slider in left of screen which slides out and take wider width(15rem)
But there is no hover thing in smartphones, so it slides out on click, i dont want this to happen

Comment: Can you explain your requirement clearly? Unable to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: I have a slider in left side of screen which slides out and take more width(15rem).. but there not hover concept in smartphones.. it opens that slider on click.. i dont want this to happen

Comment: Did either answer help you? @Biker. If either of them did, consider marking them as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The ***media queries are not selectors*** and hence you cannot pass them as an argument to the `:not` (negation) selector.  [The CSS negation selector only takes simple selectors as argument](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

Instead you should use the `@media` block with the logical `not` operator like in the below snippet: (*it is only a sample for your understanding, change the media query as per your needs*)

```
&:hover, &.hover-this {
  @media not screen {
    width: 15rem;

    .row .label-area {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: @icon-width;
    }

    + .menu { left: 16rem; }
  }
}

@icon-width: 16px;
```

---

Below is an [extract from the W3C Specs about the logical NOT operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0): (present below Example 7)

> The logical NOT can be expressed through the ‘not’ keyword. The presence of the keyword ‘not’ at the beginning of the media query negates the result. I.e., if the media query had been true without the ‘not’ keyword it will become false, and vice versa. User agents that only support media types (as described in HTML4) will not recognize the ‘not’ keyword and the associated style sheet is therefore not applied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "not" media query. Just specify the styles where exactly you want them. So in your case, leave the hover style OUT of the "small screens" section.

```
// Small screens
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    // Nothing here...
}

// Large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #something:hover {

    }
}
```